# HIIT timer variant for Android

Tags: android, time-management, timer

I'm looking for an alternative to '**[HIIT interval training timer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ihunda.android.hiit)**': A count-down timer which …

- rings when the count-down reached zero
- *continues ringing until dismissed*
- has an option to restart automatically when reaching zero (but still keeps ringing if it wasn't dismissed).
- a free app is preferred, but I'd also take a paid app

*HIIT* rings every so often, restarts automatically and shows how much time is remaining, but it doesn't ask me to dismiss whenever it rings. I'm looking for something like that but asks me to dismiss every time it rings.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please check my edit (if I got that right), and add your maximum acceptable price ;) Your question is reopened now. Good luck!

Comment: PS: There are several "Hybrid Interval Timers" (HIIT) which you might check while waiting for answers. Some promising looking candidates are: [HIIT Tabata](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hybrid.intervaltimer) and [Tabata Timer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplevision.workout.tabata). For more candidates, check [this result list](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=hiit) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I Can't Wake Up](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kog.alarmclock&hl=en) - The creator is pretty cool.

If it's for example 7:05am, you can set the alarm to 7:10am and then have it vibrate and snooze every 5 minutes. Snoozing an alarm is equivalent to dismissing a timer and then restarting it only more efficient.

Edit: Actually you can use I guess any alarm clock such as the Android Timer, but one difference is that it might be easier to snooze and so if the phone is one's pocket, then the phone might [pocket snooze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket_dialing)